# Declaring resources as needed without duplicating them

Tags: c++

Say I'm simulating food for a population:

Eat.cpp:

```
void eat()
{
    food--:
}
```

Hunt.cpp:

```
void hunt()
{
    food++;
}
```

`eat()` and `hunt()` both depend on the integer `food`. But my population simulator might include both, one, or neither of these files. How do I ensure that `food` only exists if something is included that will use it, and will only be declared once if multiple files use it? Currently my best idea is a sort of header guard, e.g.:

```
#ifndef FOOD
#define FOOD
int food = 10;
#endif
```

Comment: You should consider dropping using global variables and create a class instead.

Comment: This is an example. Please focus on the question in the title, not the code practices.

Comment: People will answer to what they see in the question. If what you are interested in is different, make your question different so it reflects your interest.

Comment: In what scenarios would you only include one of the files? How do you remove the calls to the functions in your code when you don't build the corresponding files?

Comment: The actual scenario is a modular library wherein users might need some functions but not others. The user won't be calling a function that they aren't including. But I don't really see why that matters here.

Comment: The correct answer is probably just mark it as `inline` to avoid ODR violations, and don't worry about removing it from translation units that don't use it; that is the optimizer's job.

Comment: @BrandonLyons Global variables are terrible practice; free functions are not.  The question, as presented, looks like a very bad idea, so many SO users will see that and ignore the intent behind the question.

Comment: Clearly I've misunderstood the concept of a minimum verifiable example. I'm well aware of the pluses and minuses of global variables. The data can be global or belong to a class and passed in or *whatever*. That is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the variable `food` in one central file (even if that file doesn't use it) and then declare it [`extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) in every other file that uses it. A good optimizer may be able to optimize the variable away if it is never used or referenced. I have never tested it, though.

However, this will likely not work if initialization is required. If initialization is required, you will likely want to ensure that the variable is only initialized once. This initialization would have to be done in one file only and would likely prevent the variable from being optimized away, because the variable was used (even if it was only used for initialization).

Therefore, using the preprocessor for conditional compilation, as you have described in your question, would probably be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a food.cpp module with the public variable:

```
int food = 0;
```

Also add a header file food.h with its declaration:

```
extern int food;
```

and include it:

```
#include "food.h"
```

in all modules (food.cpp, hunt.cpp and eat.cpp).

This way all modules will be using the same variable, defined once in the dedicated module.

BTW, this is rather C-like way of designing things, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep full control over how many times `food` is allocated (e.g. just once), along with its starting value, by making it a variable which should be local to whatever function manages and initiates the population simulation.  `eat` and `hunt` should then be parametrized with this (one and only) instance of food:

Eat.cpp:

```
void eat(int & food) { food--; }
```

Hunt.cpp:

```
void hunt(int & food) { food++; }
```

Here is an example simulation in which only one instances of `food` is guaranteed to exist, and where `Hunt.cpp` is never touched.

no_hunt_simulation.cpp:

```
#include "Eat.h"

void no_hunt_simulation(int & food) {
  while (food) { eat(food); }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "no_hunt_simulation.h"

int main() {
  int food = 5;
  no_hunt_simulation(food);
  std::cout << "Remaining food: " << food << std::endl; //it's 0
}
```

With `-Wall`, GCC will remind you (or a library user) if `food` is not used, in which case you can just not declare it, preventing it from being allocated.

Comment: And yes, I know this looks very simple and boneheaded.  But the fact is is that explicitly initializing variables and giving parameters to functions lets you manage a whole lot of complexity regarding resource use with much less effort than wrangling the linker (or making the end-user of a library do it), and it scales far beyond toy problems.